# Yii2 authclient Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: yii2, google-api-console, yii2-basic-app

I am implementing yii2 authclient, I created the client id in in google api console this is the redirect url I created in gogle console with the corresponding client id.

`http://mysite.x10host.com/oauth2callback`

when I access my site login this is how it looks like
`http://mysite.x10host.com/home/mysitex/public_html/web/site/login`

when I click the the google icon

400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Application: Project Default Service Account

You can email the developer of this application at: myemail@gmail.com

The redirect URI in the request: `http://mysite.x10host/home/mysitex/public_html/web/site/auth?authclient=google`

can someone help me on this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: See an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829798/yii2-google-outh2-and-scope