# redirect_uri_mismatch in eauth yii2

Tags: php, oauth, yii2

Hi good morning everyone! I'm using the OAuth 2.0 authentication with eauth yii2 library.Everything has been perfect and I have even created the credentials:https://code.google.com/apis/console/
When creating a credential the Google my application runs very well, but after some days I get this error:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
```

The solution I have so far is create a new credential and reconfigure my:

```
'clientId'     => '1234.apps.googleusercontent.com',
'clientSecret' => '###4532YVt',
```

Indeed this is very annoying for users. this is not happening with my application.I hope you understand and thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my opinion Google is a real "bad ass" with its 'redirect_uri_mismatch'. You may find a lot of similar questions in the Internet. Some of your users may have troubles with oAuth because of 'www' subdomain or http/https difference in url etc. The only reliable method I found is to use extensions 'returnUrl' config option as its said here [yii2, google outh2 and scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829798/yii2-google-outh2-and-scope)